# regular expressions in linux, grep w

Tags: regex, linux, command

I've got a short question concerning regular expressions in linux. There is a book in `.txt` format *(Dracula.txt)*. I don't know how to determine the **3 most frequent words** in this book that start with `v` and end with `e` and display them. I know I should use `grep`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use more then just `grep` for that >>

```
grep -io '\bv[a-z]*e\b' Dracula.txt | sort -f | uniq -ic | sort -nr | head -3
```

Comment: To print **only** 3 top **words** add `| cut -c9-` at the end of command line

Comment: Thanks man. It works perfectly... I knew the rest..just the regular expression '\bv[a-z]*e\b' was the problem..

Comment: @haver24 - Please accept this answer by clicking check mark below number left of my answer. Thank you.